# How to measure the color of honey?

Tags: organic-chemistry, inorganic-chemistry, experimental-chemistry, food-chemistry

After doing some research, I found that honey's color could be a factor of climate. I am very interested in this subject and I'm a high school student so we don't have as much apparatus as you would find in a chemistry school. The color of the honey can be determined using wavelengths which means a spectrometer is required and it is not available in our school. It would be very helpful if any of you recommended me with a way from which I can carry out this experiment and measure the color of honey.

Thanks for your valuable help!

Comment: A good statrting place for a literature search would be http://www.tecnofrom.com/moduloNotas/noti_67/archivosAdjuntos/AN53025-Analysis-of-Honey-Color-and-HMF-Content-FINAL-FHR_1_279.pdf

Comment: I am a high school student myself, so I understand your struggles! I have tried making a crude 'spectrophotometer' in the past when I had nothing but a camera and a computer. This is by no means a precise or accepted way of doing things, but it should definitely give you a start. Place your samples in a clear container of know volume and take a picture of them (a the same location) in front of a white background. You can then upload your photos to an online RGB color picker and use a chart to convert the RGB values to a wavelength. This has worked fairly well for me.

Comment: It is important to note that a diffraction grating is used to separate the constituent colors of your light. If you take photos of your samples, they will most definitely contain a mixture of light (thus you should use a diffraction grating); however, because you are only comparing samples relative to each other, this is probably not that relevant for your intents and purposes.

Comment: Hello @EliJones, sounds like a good method to use but since I'm doing this experiment from a chemistry perspective point, to what extent do measuring wavelengths in colors of honey involve chemistry?

Comment: I believe you said your goal was to perform a correlational study between the color of honey and the climate. In this case, it is irrelevant wheater or not your measurements are based on the wavelength of light absorbed or the color of honey. If you wanted to try to perform a correlational study between wavelength and climate, that would be much more difficult to interpret. This is because the light absorbed by honey is a mixture of colors. As you might imagine, using a spectrophotometer to obtain a complex mixture of colors won't provide the best data to interpret!

Comment: For the purpose of your experiment, I would probably just determine the color of the honey. The wavelength of light absorbed is generally used to determine structural properties of a certain compound -- such as the presence of multiple double bonds or a hydrated copper (II) complex. Because you are not actually analyzing molecular properties per say, spectroscopy is not really necessary.

Answer (score 11):

Could you use a reference color chart? Here is one originally made for skin colors:

[image: eSkin Color Chart]

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_chart) has other examples.
Paint stores might give you a nicely printed color chart for free.

There are also online versions of color selectors, for example the one from [Pantone](https://www.pantone.com/color-finder), but then you have to be very careful about color calibrating your screen, or at least not changing it between comparisons.

A third option, more realistic if you are only measuring color along one scale, would be to make your own comparison material. Start with a light honey colored liquid and mix in a darker color till it matches your honey. The amount of dark color used gives you the darkness of the honey. You probably have all supplies available in the art department.

Edit:

MaxW found a much better solution, a special color scale for honey. It is called the Pfund scale:
[image: Pfund scale]

Comment: The [Pfund scale](https://www.google.com/search?q=Pfund+scale&client=firefox-b-1-d&tbm=isch&source=iu&ictx=1&fir=zQuRipwQkDNRoM%253A%252CvHhTfL0BvfPu9M%252C_&vet=1&usg=AI4_-kTyj0QmNczxcHJlzWd1QhRu1RDyXg&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwia0pGK46jpAhUBT98KHbaWBl0Q9QEwAnoECAoQEw#imgrc=hpNRq_X5lh213M) mentioned in the link I provided is such a color reference for honey. From a image of the scale, and using a color picker on the computer, you could judiciously select the appropriate paint chips to make a reasonable facsimile.  You'd have to figure out the "standard" thickness of honey which to view the color.

Answer (score 6):

If you haven't already, try asking a biology teacher if they have a spectrometer. High school biology departments often have a UV-Vis spectrometer.

You can also try making your own spectrometer [using a CD as a diffraction grating](http://coolcosmos.ipac.caltech.edu/cosmic_games/spectra/makeGrating.htm). You can then use [this site](https://sci-toys.com/scitoys/scitoys/light/spectrograph/spectrograph.html) to upload a photograph of the spectrum for quantitative analysis.

Honey is a very good candidate for use in a simple homemade visible light spectrometer.

Comment: You wouldn't need a spectrometer. Good LED's are monochromatic enough for such a crude characterization.

Comment: hello @MaxW, sounds like a good method and I finally found a spectrometer to use but since I'm doing this experiment from a chemistry perspective point, to what extent do measuring wavelengths in colors of honey involve chemistry?

Comment: @chemistryenthusiast - UV-Vis Spectrometry follows [Beer's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beer%E2%80%93Lambert_law) which requires a monochromatic source.